# How to improve Cython performance?

Tags: python, performance, cython

I am doing my first steps with Cython, and I am wondering how to improve performance even more.
Until now I got to half the usual (python only) execution time, but I think there must be more!

I know `cython -a` and I already typed my variables. But there is still a lot in yellow in my function. Is this because cython does not recognise numpy or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can benefit by using math functions from libc as you are calling np.sqrt and np.floor on scalars. This has not only the Python call overhead but there are different code paths in the numpy ufuncs for scalars and arrays. So that involves at least a type switch.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a problem, as I've tested with the [official tutorial](http://wiki.cython.org/tutorials/numpy), it's also reported as yellow on every np.* lines, and involves python just the same as your code.

Point 3 at the end of that page should have explained this:

> Calling NumPy/SciPy functions currently has a Python call overhead; it would be possible to take a short-cut from Cython directly to C. (This does however require some isolated and incremental changes to those libraries; mail the Cython mailing list for details).

Comment: ah okai, I did not notice that before!